# how to display the information inside an object

Tags: java, object

we are assigned to implement the inside of a code block wherein it is associated with a given class (EmployeeProjectDetail) which is declared as a arraylist.

my code follows below.

```
public List<EmployeeProjectDetail> getEmployeeProjectHistory(long employeeID, long projectID) {

List<EmployeeProjectDetail> detailList = new ArrayList<EmployeeProjectDetail>();
return detailList;
}
```

I tried inputting the statements.

```
detailList.contains(projectDAO.getEmployeeProjects(employeeID));
detailList.contains(projectDAO.getEmployeeProjectRoles(employeeID, projectID));
```

the code then doesn't return any value but the invovled sql queries in projectDAO class are thoroughly handled. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I do not see there are any `EmployeeProjectDetail` objects added to the `detailList` .  So , the returned `detailList` contains nothing is normal .

Answer (score 3):

[contains](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) checks whether an item is in a list what your are looking for is [add](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28java.lang.Object%29).

You should add the line

```
detailList.add(projectDAO.getEmployeeProjects(employeeID));
```

---

**Update (I'm guessing on the method and class names)**

Based on the ClassCastException it appears that `getEmployeeProjects(employeeID)` returns an `ArrayList`. If the objects in this `ArrayList` are `EmployeeProjectDetail`'s you can just replace the method body with `return projectDAO.getEmployeeProjects(employeeID);`. If they are a different object representing a project, say `EmployeeProject`, you would need to replace the method body with the following code:

```
List<Project> projects = projectDAO.getEmployeeProjects(employeeID);
ArrayList<EmployeeProjectDetail> projectDetails = new ArrayList<EmployeeProjectDetail>();
for (Project project : projects) {
    if(project.getProjectID == projectID){
        projectDetails.add(project.getProjectDetail());
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried that but the program doesn't allow casting. java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to sef.domain.EmployeeProjectDetail

Comment: What type of object does getEmployeeProjects(employeeID) return?

Comment: getEmployeeProjects also return a list associated to a class. List<Project> list

Comment: I've updated my answer. You should get all the projects belonging to an employee, then return all ProjectDetails that belong to the Project with the appropriate projectID.